# ExpressionEngine UPS Shipping plugin causes Guzzle HTTP exception

Tags: php, expressionengine, tls1.2, ups

Website spec:

- Apache
- PHP version 5.4
- OpenSSL 1.0.2_8
- ExpressionEngine 2.10.3
- Expresso Store 2.5.1
- Store UPS Shipping 1.1.0 (Expresso Store extension)

The error occurs during checkout. Here is the checkout flow:

- `/checkout/1` Cart detail page
- `/checkout/2` Form for billing and shipping information. Shipping cost calculation happens on this page.
- `/checkout/3` Form for credit card information.
- `/checkout/receipt/ORDER_HASH` Receipt page.

The issue happens on page 2. Once the shipping info is entered, the user clicks the calculate button, triggering a request to the UPS API for estimated shipping cost. The page reloads with the UPS response of all the valid shipping options and estimated costs.

According to a [notice from UPS](https://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/techsupport/data-security.html), TLSv1.0 and v1.1 no longer works in test mode.

However, the UPS Shipping plugin negotiates the cipher suite using the TLSv1 spec (not just v1.2). The request is hitting a load balancer and is sent to various servers. Some servers still support v1.0 and others require v1.2. So I get an error roughly half the time.

The error occurs in the [Guzzle HTTP client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' 
with message '[curl] 35: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate'
in /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php:338 
Stack trace: 
#0 /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(279): 
    Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->isCurlException(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) 
#1 /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(244): 
    Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) 
#2 /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(227): 
    Guzzle\Http\Curl\Cur in /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 338
```

The shipping plugin hasn't been updated in a while so this UPS API upgrade hasn't been accounted for. In the meantime, I'm looking to patch it on my own.

I suspect the problem is line 143 of the send() function in this file:

```
/.../system/expressionengine/third_party/store_ups/ApiRequest.php
```

The line:

```
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

I'm not sure what string value to pass to it to force the request to use TLSv1.2. Tried using the string `'TLSv1.2'` but that did not work. Got the string value from [OpenSSL's manpages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-STRINGS).

Comment: It's possible that *your* server does not support TLSv1.2  From the command line try: openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2

Comment: @AllInOne the server does support TLSv1.2. I've verified a few times. The issue happens when making the initial handshake with the UPS server. When I hit the UPS API a second time, it works without issue.